# Как хранить Id в массиве и передавать функции document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть массив со всеми id на странице(которые надо заменить)

```
var ClassBlockName = ["'Intro_2'" , "'whatWeDo_2'" , "'workProcess_2'" , "'whyUs_2'" , "'Prices_2'" , "'Order_2'"];
```

Мне необходимо перебрать все ячейки массива и заменить их цвет(например на черный)

```
    for(var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    document.getElementById(ClassBlockName[i]).style.color = '#000';
}
```

Но при выполнении выдает ошибку : Cannot read property 'style' of null.

Comment: У вас в массиве квычки в кавычках, ищется id = `'Intro_2'`, а надо скорее всего `Intro_2`

Comment: Побывал ставить без кавычек, выдает тоже самое.

Comment: @ДмитрийНиколаевич, тебе возвращает `null` потому что элемента с таким `id` нет в момент вызова данной функции. В предоставленном коде очевидный недочет с кавычками. Если их удаление не помогает, значит либо функция вызывается слишком рано, либо нужно смотреть какой именно `id` стоит в разметке.  Для получения более конкретного ответа стоит добавить в вопрос [mcve] чтобы видно было когда вызывается скрипт и что находится в самой разметке.

Comment: Редактировать лучше предыдущий вопрос.